# Integrating Facebook in iOS using Parse Mobile Platform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to run a simple iPhone application [using Parse o integrate with facebook](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers).

You can easily download the project [here](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios)

The problem is when I login to facebook, I go to this page:

[image]

When I click on the Okay button, I get this error message:

[image]

So It does not navigate to the next ViewController (UserDetailsViewController).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the app URL scheme for you app to the `info.plst`

Since you did not add this, iOS does not know how to open you app.

Adde the following to your apps `info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb<YOUR APPS FACEBOOK ID></string>
            <string><YOU APPS NAME></string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

And replace the  with you apps facebook ID but leaf the fb, it should look like `fb1231654354`.

Comment: Are you talking about : `Add a new entry in the URL Types section of your project info, with the format "fbYOUR_FB_APP_ID":` that is mentioned in the tutorial? If you mean this, I did it.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, but did you replace the `YOUR_FB_APP_ID` with you facebook app ID?

Comment: Check it, because the error shows that iOS does not about the app URL scheme and there is unable to open your app. The problem should be in the `CFBundleURLSchemes`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid fb which you written prior to your app_id in delegate file..
fb is needed only in urlScheme

Comment: Please do not make your whole post **bold**. Bold is only to highlight very important, single words.