# iOS App Link can be opened from gmail/safari but not from facebook/twitter

Tags: ios, facebook, ios9, deep-linking, applinks

i try to open an iOS application from facebook/twitter iOS apps.

For that i use App link, using the key in `info.plist` : `CFBundleURLSchemes`.

What i do, in order to have an acceptable link in twitter/facebook post i use a fake webpage which has the function to redirect me to the url link of my app . 
eg: "myapp://"

This works fine if i open my facebook post (url) using safari.

But when it comes to facebook/twitter apps , it redirects to the new webpage but it doesn't prompt the popup to open my app. I can see in the logs error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme myapp"

My first understand was that this is due to iOS 9 restriction where you should mention in your whitelist [`LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`] which app urls you are accepting to open from your app.

But surprisingly when trying to open the same webpage from gmail application (which is not OS app) it opens my application without issues.

Am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: i guess this is because that facebook/twitter are not using default iOS browser ,they are not able to open any app unless they list it in info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

Comment: This could be because of the way, as you mentioned, that Facebook and Twitter internal browsers handle Universal Links. A lot of various apps and browsers break Universal Links (pertinent to iOS9.2 and later), and this includes Facebook and Twitter in many cases. You can sometimes make this work for Twitter and/or Facebook if there is a webview already open. They do not work in-app from the feed / main views. They also must be cross-domain.

Comment: i fixed this by using metadata in my web page.
for facebook they call it "App Link" , and for twitter : "App card"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify in `CFBundleURLSchemes` the scheme for Facebook and Twitter. Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838039/integrating-facebook-in-ios-using-parse-mobile-platform) for the Facebook solution.

**EDIT**

I've followed this steps and all worked out. Facebook tutorial for [App Links on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios). 
Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: same it doesn't work..even if i try to open fb<appId> in safari it works but not in facebook app.